# C# Vlc Player Mouse Double Click Event

Tags: c#, mouseevent, vlc, double-click, libvlc

I am working on a player developed using libvlc, c#. There is working fullscreen button. I tried to add mousedoubleclick event to panel(plays video), its working when we are not playing video; but it does not work when video starts to play. Therefore i have added same event into player but still does not work.

Definition of Event:

```
this.player.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseDoubleClick);
```

Definition:

```
private vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl player;
```

Is there any other way to add mouse double click event into vlc player?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Panel1:** "panelVideo" holds "Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl"

**Panel2:** "panelDoubleClick" created  at runtime and "vlcControl.Controls.Add(panelDoubleClick);"

**Panel2:** set panelDoubleClick.BackColor = **Color.Transparent**;

**Panel2:** add double click event hantler for toggle full screen panelDoubleClick.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(panelDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick);

```
    Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl vlcControl;
    Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia Media2Play;

    public void PlayMedia(string fileName)
    {

        if (Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.IsInitialized == false)
            initVLC();

        //StopVLC();

        //Panel1: "panelVideo" holds "Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl"
        //Panel2: "panelDoubleClick" created  at runtime and "vlcControl.Controls.Add(panelDoubleClick);" 
        //Panel2: panelDoubleClick.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        //panelDoubleClick.MouseDoubleClick += panelDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick;


        vlcControl = new Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl();
        vlcControl.CreateControl();
        vlcControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelVideo.Controls.Add(vlcControl);//panelVideo is manin container panel.
        //initEvents();//VLC player events


        Panel panelDoubleClick = new Panel();// this panel requires to catche double click evetns.
        panelDoubleClick.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelDoubleClick.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        panelDoubleClick.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(panelDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick); ;

        if (vlcControl != null)
        {
            Media2Play = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(fileName);
            vlcControl.Media = Media2Play;
            vlcControl.Show();
            vlcControl.Play();
            vlcControl.Controls.Add(panelDoubleClick);
            panelDoubleClick.BringToFront();
        }

    }

    private void panelDoubleClick_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show  ("ToggleFullScreen();");
    }

    private void initVLC()
    {

        try
        {
            // Set libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll directory path
            string vlcPath = "";

            vlcPath = "E:\\VLC\\VLC_minimal";

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(vlcPath) == false)
            {
                vlcPath = Application.StartupPath.Trim('\\') + "\\VLC\\";
                if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(vlcPath) == false)
                {
                    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                    {
                        vlcPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vlcPath = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC";
                    }
                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(vlcPath) == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("VLC cannot be fount on your system.");
                        Application.Exit();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath = vlcPath;


            // CommonStrings.LIBVLC_DLLS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;

            // Set the vlc plugins directory path
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.LibVlcPluginsPath = Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.LibVlcDllsPath + "\\pugins";
            //CommonStrings.PLUGINS_PATH_DEFAULT_VALUE_AMD64;

            // Ignore the VLC configuration file
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.IgnoreConfig = true;

            // Enable file based logging
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.LogInFile = false;

            // Shows the VLC log console (in addition to the applications window)
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.ShowLoggerConsole = false;

            // Set the log level for the VLC instance
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.LogOptions.Verbosity = Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcLogVerbosities.None;

            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.ScreenSaverEnabled = false;
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.StartupOptions.AddOption("--no-video-title");
            //hide played media filename on startingto play media.

            // Initialize the VlcContext
            Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcContext.Initialize();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```